# How do I configure additional phone lines asterisk/trixbox?

Tags: linux, voip, asterisk, freepbx, trixbox

I have a 4 port Digium card in there, and have 4 lines running smoothly. Now, we added ANOTHER 4 port card **1AEX410PELF** and have 4 more analog lines coming into the Trixbox server. It still runs the 4 fine, but what do I need to do to add the additional 4 phone numbers/lines?

I want it to act exactly as before, there's nothing special about the new lines. We just need more lines so that when we have 4 out of state customers call, we can have 4 more call and not get the busy signal.

Trixbox CE 2.8

bob is the name of the server

Comment: What card do you have?

Comment: 1AEX410PELF card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have worked:

1. Make sure you have the FXO modules installed/added onto the 2nd card
2. Run dadhi_genconf and check /etc/dahdi/system.conf
3. Run dadhi_scan and make sure it’s showing 8 lines and that the “alarms=UNCONFIGURED” is gone from the second card
4. Reboot entire server

Answer (score 0):

SSH to your box and type `setup-pstn` in your console it should install it automatically, then proceed to configure your trunks and routes in web-UI.

*Tell me if it doesn't work, it sometimes depends on the card.*

Comment: Did something, but then got in some kind of "restarting Asterisk" loop so we just restarted the actual machine and it came back better. Didn't light up the lights on the new card.

Comment: [bob asterisk]# setup-pstn

--------------------------------------------------------------
Detecting PSTN cards and USB PSTN Devices
--------------------------------------------------------------


PCI Hardware found
Hardware present!



STOPPING ASTERISK
Asterisk Stopped

STOPPING FOP SERVER
FOP Server Stopped
Asterisk appears to still be running please stop asterisk and try again!
[bob asterisk]# setup-pstn
[bob asterisk]# /etc/init.d/asterisk start
Starting PBXtra Core service:                              [  OK  ]

Comment: Waiting 5 seconds for dahdi to recover
Asterisk ended with exit status 1
Asterisk died with code 1.
Automatically restarting Asterisk.
mpg123: no process killed
Asterisk ended with exit status 1
Asterisk died with code 1.
Automatically restarting Asterisk.
Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
/etc/init.d/asterisk: line 141: /etc/init.d/FONmon: No such file or directory
[bob asterisk]# mpg123: no process killed
Asterisk ended with exit status 1